# C# get the value when first time the array element is null

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, null

get when first time element value is null
I want to add the value at that position

```
a[0]=0
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=3
a[4]=null --- add 4 here                                                          
a[5]=null
a[6]=null
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please explain what  you are trying to do more clearly.

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT Hello , just want a condition to find when my array element is null for first time

Comment: thank you, i'll develop an answer right away.

Comment: Maybe you want to change the type of `a` from an array to a `List<>`? With a `List<>`, you can use `a.Add(4);`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, that does not make sense considering what is his question, he asked how to get the index (i guess) of the first null element, using a growable collection here would be completely futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array, check values. if you encounter null, do the thing.

```
for(int i = 0; i< a.Length; i++)
{
    if(a[i] == null)
    {
        // do something
        
        // use break if you dont want to continue
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: @Serge Are you referring to the typo in `Length`?

Comment: @Serge Surely it will work. What was the type of `a` when you tried?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I am sorry. It is ok. I just realized that I made a children error - forgot about {};

Comment: @Serge I think the compiler will issue a **warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected** about the `i++` if you `break;` unconditionally. The loop will never be a real loop if you break out in all cases, and the control flow will never get to the point where `i++` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it was tested

```
var i=0;
    
    for ( i=0;  i<a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]==null) break;
    }
      if(i<a.Length) a[i]=4;
```

Comment: This is useless. It will not modify an entry in `a`. And `b` is simply `null`, unless an exception occurs, so the condition under the `if` seems to be never satisfied?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I am sorry, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to check with the comparison operator.
"your_list?=null"

Comment: if,switch or while

Comment: if .... but  what about the position of the element ??

Comment: you could keep track of it by adding an int variable and icrementing it during the loop

Comment: @Developer_Raghu there is no such thing as an if loop. I know, pedantic comment but important to understand the difference between decisions and loops

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Using a foreach would not be a bad idea:

```cs
foreach (var element in a)
{
    if (element is null) break; // or do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array a and check for every iteration if the value in the array is null.

Example:

```
for(int i; i < a.Length; i++) {
    if (a[i] is null) {
        //Do your work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not C# related question actually. It is more about algorithms.

If talking about C#, first of all, if you are going to compare with Nulls, that means that you need to use Nullable type (e.g. int?[] in your case).

The solution is: You need to loop from the 0th element until nth-1 and at each step to compare value with Null. If Null item is at ith index, then replace a[i] with a new value and exit the cycle.

You can loop using *for*, *foreach*, or different Linq methods.